# SimonVT menudrawer

Tags: java, android, menu

I have an app that already many activities and class. Like Profile, Friends, Photos, News Feed, etc. I want to integrate that sliding drawer into my main activities. in the examples, they are just showing array list which is implement onClick. so my question is how to change that array list to become my activities like friends, profile, home and etc.

Comment: why don't you just create a listview with these items and in every onitemclick open different activity.

Comment: so using listview and list activity? or just using listview?

Comment: doesn't matter,you can do the both. You can't set activity as listview item. You need to find a way to populate your listview and set onitemclick to do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ListView with custom adapter. to adjust custom adapter you can link in your listView that adapter. and in adapter you can put custom icon

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View rowView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);

    ImageView icon = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.row_icon);
    TextView title = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.row_title);

    title.setText(proMenu[position]);

    String s = proMenu[position];

    if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("Home")){
        icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_home);
    }

    else
        if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("Best Nearby")){
            icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.specialss);
        }
```